Can we keep app running on background with interval every 5 seconds?
I'm new to react-native and require some guidance on understanding how a function can run when app is minimised. I found this library: react-native-background-fetch. From this library, it's said that the minimumFetchInterval is 15 mins by default and that is the minimum. Is it possible to lower the value to, let's say, 5 seconds? Because I imagine there may be api calls that needs to be sent every few seconds when app is in background and 15 mins seems a bit of a time. Any input is appreciated. Thank you

Did you read why that is the way it is?

@DaveNewton in the doc, it does say that it's due to OS restriction but I'm wondering if it's possible/or if there's a way to make it happen because I'm sure there are api calls being done in the background for less than 15 mins.

@tiredqa_18 I don't think that react-native-background-fetch or react-native-background-task can increase its frequency than that of 15 minutes, but here I found another plugin called react-native-background-actions. Though I'm not sure about the results yet, but you can give it a try as it allows you to place any action such as setInterval, etc.

@Snehal yeah seems like it's really not possible then. I'll have a look at the react-native-background-actions plugin you shared. thanks!

So I read their documentation. It says you can change the time. But you can't go higher than 15 minutes and you can go lower than 15 minutes. Here is what they mentioned on their GitHub docs:

The minimum interval in minutes to execute background fetch events.
Defaults to 15 minutes. Note: Background-fetch events will never occur
at a frequency higher than every 15 minutes. Apple uses a secret
algorithm to adjust the frequency of fetch events, presumably based
upon usage patterns of the app. Fetch events can occur less often than
your configured minimumFetchInterval.

Here is a sample code for 5 seconds:
import BackgroundFetch from 'react-native-background-fetch';

BackgroundFetch.configure({
  minimumFetchInterval: 5/60, //(mins/60) Set the minimum fetch interval to 5 seconds
}, async (taskId) => {
  // Your background fetch logic here
  console.log('Background fetch task executed');
}, (error) => {
  console.error('Failed to configure background fetch', error);
});

However, I would suggest further investigating their API support for the time values. Because 5 seconds is a very short time for such a free service. They may have a minimum limit of 1 min.

hey, thanks for the reply. Can you confirm if it can actually go lower? Because I read the description in the documentation and it said  that
There is no way to increase the rate which a fetch-event occurs and this plugin sets the rate to the most frequent possible — you will never receive an event faster than 15 minutes.
``` so I assumed it won't go lower than that but maybe I misunderstood.
